# How do I move the cursor within the command prompt below the currently printing material in python?

Tags: python

I need to be able to input beneath this code that prints Loading, Loading., Loading.., etc. The problem is that I don't know how to put the blinking cursor in the command prompt below the "Loading" code. I already have the code for input which I am threading in. The code for the "Loading" is below; any help is appreciated.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
        b = "Loading" + "." * x
        print(b, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The blinking cursor indicates that the shell is ready for input, but, while it's printing and sleeping in that loop, it isn't ready for input. To your program's user, it's still "loading" anyway.

Comment: I don't believe that can be done easily in a portable way, because different operational systems or even terminal programs have different ways of doing that. Luckily there are libraries out there that already deal with that for us, like `curses`.